# Tab trigger action in certain program

Tags: autohotkey

What is wrong with this script?

Here is the code and waht i try to accomplish

```
TAB::
IfWinActive, MyLfeOrganized
Send ^!{Right}
return
```

Where ^! is shift and alt key at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [context-sensitive hotkey](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) to accomplish this.

```
#IfWinActive, MyLfeOrganized
TAB::
    Send, ^!{Right}
return
#If
```

This hotkey will only work if the `#IfWinActive` condition is met. Otherwise it will leave your <kbd>TAB</kbd> key alone.

Comment: the document I have opened is named *ppp.ml* so the window name is *ppp.ml - MyLifeOrganized* the script only works with *#IfWinActive, ppp.ml* why is that?

Comment: @user1603548 That's due to how AHK matches titles. The default is to look for titles that _start_ with the `WinTitle`. You can change this by using `SetTitleMatchMode, 2`. You can read more [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm).